# linq query operator 'Any' Not supported

Tags: linq, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-entities

using the following LINQ query:

```
EntityQuery<Questions> query = context.GetQuestionsQuery()
                  .Where(o => o.SurveyQuestions.Any(o2 => o2.SurveyID == 3));
```

However when using LINQPad...it works fine.

```
Questions.Where(o => o.SurveyQuestions.Any(o2 => o2.SurveyID == 3)).Dump();
```

is this a limitation of Silverlight? If so How can i do the same thing in a silverlight friendly way? On a little more investigation this looks like its being caused in the DomainContext.Load operation.

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>   Timestamp: Mon, 28 Feb 2011 18:06:11
>   UTC
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight 2 Application Query
>   operator 'Any' is not supported.   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.BeginQueryCore(EntityQuery
>   query, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   userState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.BeginQuery(EntityQuery
>   query, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   userState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load(EntityQuery
>   query, LoadBehavior loadBehavior,
>   Action`1 callback, Object userState)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load[TEntity](EntityQuery`1
>   query, LoadBehavior loadBehavior,
>   Action`1 callback, Object userState)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load[TEntity](EntityQuery`1
>   query, Action`1 callback, Object
>   userState)    at
>   ReadmissionTrackingApplication.Client.ViewModel.QuestionairreViewModel.ReceiveNewQuestionairreRequest(fnReadmitPatientList_Result
>   request)    at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.WeakAction`1.Execute(T
>   parameter)    at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.WeakAction`1.ExecuteWithObject(Object
>   parameter)    at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.SendToList[TMessage](TMessage
>   message, IEnumerable`1 list, Type
>   messageTargetType, Object token)    at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.SendToTargetOrType[TMessage](TMessage
>   message, Type messageTargetType,
>   Object token)    at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Send[TMessage](TMessage
>   message)    at
>   ReadmissionTrackingApplication.Client.ViewModel.PrimarySearchViewModel.OpenSurveyCommand_Execute()
>   at
>   ReadmissionTrackingApplication.Client.ViewModel.PrimarySearchViewModel.b__2()
>   at
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand.Execute(Object
>   parameter)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control
>   ctrl, EventArgs e)    at
>   MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr
>   unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs,
>   Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32
>   actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
>   Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://localhost/readdtrackapp/Silverlight.js

Comment: I moved this into an IQueryable Query on my DomainService and it now works. I am still curious though as to why it wont work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because not all the LINQ queries are supported by `EntityQuery` class. Only the following operators would work with EntityQuery:

- Where
- OrderBy
- ThenBy
- Skip
- Take

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entityquery%28v=vs.91%29.aspx